# Error on Nextcloud OpenID Connect login with Authelia

Tags: docker-compose, openid-connect, nginx-reverse-proxy, nextcloud

I am currently trying to set up and use Authelia idendity providers with OpenID Connect as a single login provider for several different applications.

The first application I want to add is Nextcloud. To do this, I follow the instructions on the Authelia documentation page: https://www.authelia.com/integration/openid-connect/nextcloud

But the problem I'm facing now is that I always get an error message saying that the redirect URL I specified in the configuration is not valid, even though I used the official URL from the Authelia docs.

Authelia Error:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "The request is missing a required parameter, 
      includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, 
      or is otherwise malformed. The 'redirect_uri' parameter does not match 
      any of the OAuth 2.0 Client's pre-registered redirect urls."
}
```

Authelia Configuration:
(Replaced my server address by: "example.com")

```
jwt_secret: ac5Tmfbue44TxPTrCpCWNNZKm7AmvBS6
default_redirection_url: https://example.com

server:
  host: 0.0.0.0
  port: 9091

log:
  level: debug

totp:
  issuer: example.com

authentication_backend:
  file:
    path: /config/users_database.yml

access_control:
  default_policy: one_factor
  rules:
    - domain: auth.example.com
      policy: bypass
    - domain:
        - example.com
        - proxy.example.com
        - nextcloud.example.com
      policy: one_factor

identity_providers:
  oidc:
    hmac_secret: GhuVkMctBBFratABE6fMUacCWKhGgNa23SuDuN62Ug6vxQhJJTsLXca3ZdXyuL7n
    issuer_private_key: {KEY}
    access_token_lifespan: 1h
    authorize_code_lifespan: 1m
    id_token_lifespan: 1h
    refresh_token_lifespan: 90m
    enable_client_debug_messages: false
    enforce_pkce: public_clients_only
    cors:
      endpoints:
        - authorization
        - token
        - revocation
        - introspection
      allowed_origins:
        - https://example.com
      allowed_origins_from_client_redirect_uris: false
    clients:
      - id: nextcloud
        secret: nextcloud_client_secret
        public: false
        authorization_policy: one_factor
        scopes:
          - openid
          - profile
          - groups
        redirect_uris:
          - https://nextcloud.example.com/apps/oidc_login/oidc
        userinfo_signing_algorithm: none

session:
  name: authelia_session
  secret: kHT5S9ed8ArygSwyVZWm48Pyjt4qyXg9
  expiration: 3600
  inactivity: 300
  domain: example.com

regulation:
  max_retries: 3
  find_time: 120
  ban_time: 300

storage:
  encryption_key: nqcWgCG22YM6Uttj4GQw5eeNsWKwr4Xm
  local:
    path: /config/db.sqlite3

notifier:
  filesystem:
    filename: /config/notification.txt
```

Nextcloud Configuration:
(Plugin: OpenID Connect Login)

```
<?php
$CONFIG = array (
  'htaccess.RewriteBase' => '/',
  'memcache.local' => '\\OC\\Memcache\\APCu',
  'apps_paths' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'path' => '/var/www/html/apps',
      'url' => '/apps',
      'writable' => false,
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'path' => '/var/www/html/custom_apps',
      'url' => '/custom_apps',
      'writable' => true,
    ),
  ),
  'instanceid' => 'owd1s341ok',
  'passwordsalt' => 'Kt7fjLgAGjGMtAdrfdsXR4BEEz5pqzmv',
  'secret' => '64kSvSXtpQ2HUMBEdQTf5NusZ9SnQhBN64kSvSXtpQ2HUe',
  'trusted_domains' => 
  array (
    0 => 'nextcloud.example.com',
  ),
  'datadirectory' => '/var/www/html/data',
  'dbtype' => 'sqlite3',
  'version' => '24.0.1.1',
  'overwrite.cli.url' => 'http://nextcloud.example.com',
  'installed' => true,
  'allow_user_to_change_display_name' => false,
  'lost_password_link' => 'disabled',
  'oidc_login_provider_url' => 'https://auth.example.com',
  'oidc_login_client_id' => 'nextcloud',
  'oidc_login_client_secret' => 'nextcloud_client_secret',
  'oidc_login_auto_redirect' => false,
  'oidc_login_end_session_redirect' => false,
  'oidc_login_button_text' => 'Log in with Authelia',
  'oidc_login_hide_password_form' => false,
  'oidc_login_use_id_token' => true,
  'oidc_login_attributes' => array (
    'id' => 'preferred_username',
    'name' => 'name',
    'mail' => 'email',
    'groups' => 'groups',
  ),
  'oidc_login_default_group' => 'oidc',
  'oidc_login_use_external_storage' => false,
  'oidc_login_scope' => 'openid profile groups',
  'oidc_login_proxy_ldap' => false,
  'oidc_login_disable_registration' => true,
  'oidc_login_redir_fallback' => false,
  'oidc_login_alt_login_page' => 'assets/login.php',
  'oidc_login_tls_verify' => true,
  'oidc_create_groups' => false,
  'oidc_login_webdav_enabled' => false,
  'oidc_login_password_authentication' => false,
  'oidc_login_public_key_caching_time' => 86400,
  'oidc_login_min_time_between_jwks_requests' => 10,
  'oidc_login_well_known_caching_time' => 86400,
  'oidc_login_update_avatar' => false,
);
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this error or what I need to change to make it work?
(I am using Nginx Proxy Manager as a reverse proxy and Docker to run Nginx Proxy Manager, Authelia and Nextcloud).

Thanks
Ypselon :)

**-= Update =-**

I noticed that when I try to log in with Authelia, I get the error page with the following URL:

```
https://auth.example.com/api/oidc/authorization?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%nextcloud.example.com%2Fapps%2Foidc_login%2Foidc&client_id=nextcloud&nonce=9a2986f054d7044bcb3050ed3c38a1b6&state=9384d2d39924b436f8a0eb6b8bd334ad&scope=openid+profile+groups+openid
```

I can then simply remove the "redirect_uri" from the query parameters, reload the page and then for some magical reason I am presented with the consent request and after I accept it I get logged in.

Now I'm completely confused, but maybe someone can tell me, based on the behavior, where the problem might be.

Thanks
Ypselon :)

Comment: have you ever solved this? having exactly same issue

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error and started from scratch with the config from [here](https://github.com/pulsejet/nextcloud-oidc-login)

Ran into another error later, but I hope this helps you,

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and I fixed it by changing the `redirect_uris` to `https://nextcloud.example.com/index.php/apps/oidc_login/oidc` (mind the `index.php`).

If the error is based on the redirect URI's value being invalid, check the URL  of the OIDC response to see the actual redirect URI it's trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. You need to set `'overwriteprotocol' => 'https';` in your config. Watch out the `'overwritecondaddr'` can interfere here, so change it if the overwrite protocol config does not work.